# Jenkins fails to stars after upgrading Debian 7.8 to 8.7

Tags: linux, jenkins, debian-jessie

I upgraded my linux box from 7.8 to 8.7 that I used for CI server. Whenever I start jenkin service

**> sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start**

I get the following error message.

> [....] Starting jenkins (via systemctl): jenkins.serviceJob for
>   jenkins.service failed. See 'systemctl status jenkins.service' and
>   'journalctl -xn' for details. failed!

Running **systemctl status jenkins.service** gives me following detail:

> ● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time    Loaded: loaded
>   (/etc/init.d/jenkins)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu
>   2017-03-30 16:05:51 UTC; 2min 26s ago   Process: 1292
>   ExecStop=/etc/init.d/jenkins stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>   Process: 2437 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited,
>   status=7)

and running **journalctl -xe** gives me this:

> The result is failed.
>   systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state. sudo[2421]:
>   pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root sudo[2539]:
>   development : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/development ; USER=root ;
>   COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe udo[2539]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session
>   opened for user root by development(uid=0)

Both are really unhelpful. I tried to upgrade jenkin with following command

**sudo apt-get update** It comes with Ignore tag

> Ign http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org binary/ Translation-en_GB Ign
>   Ign http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org binary/ Translation-en

**sudo apt-get install jenkins**

> jenkins is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed,
>   0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Is any way I can update or repair the Jenkin service without losing the old data or setting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can You please show us the output of

```
apt-cache policy jenkins
```

I would like to see what versions of jenkins from which repository you have.

Please, also check jenkins logs. They should be in:

```
/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log
```